# I2P option "Laptop mode"

Tags: privacy, i2p

I2P has an option called `Laptop Mode`. [Documentation says](https://geti2p.net/en/docs/api/i2pcontrol) :

> change router identity and UDP port when IP changes

What's the reasoning for this option? Is it really about laptops?

Is there any academic paper that describes the privacy leak implications if this option is not enabled when it's supposed to be?